# QML Rectangle Object coming in wrong place

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols

I am just trying to create 4 rectangles with 3 next to each other and 4th one is below the 3rd rectangle and my qml looks like below

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Rectangle")

    Item{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle {
            id: firstRect
            width:50
            height:50
            color: "#ff0000"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: secondRect
            width:firstRect.width
            height: firstRect.height
            color: "blue"
            //opacity: 0.5
            anchors.left: firstRect.right
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: thirdRect
            width:firstRect.width
            height: firstRect.height
            color: "green"
            //opacity: 0.5
            anchors.left: secondRect.right
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: fourthrect
            width:firstRect.width
            height: firstRect.height
            color: "green"
            //opacity: 0.5
            anchors.top: thirdRect.bottom
        }

    }
}
```

But i am getting the 4th rectangle below the first rectangle like below even though my anchor is `thirdRect.Bottom`  what am i doing wrong
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly there, you're close. Just need to anchor it horizontally under the third rectangle.

```
Rectangle {
    id: fourthrect
    width:firstRect.width
    height: firstRect.height
    color: "green"

    anchors.top: thirdRect.bottom
    anchors.left: thirdRect.left     //  <-- this
}
```

Note that, assuming both the third and fourth rectangles have the same width, it's also possible to use `anchors.right: thirdRect.right` or `anchors.horizontalCenter: thirdRect.horizontalCenter`.

Setting `anchors.top: thirdRect.bottom` will only anchor the item *vertically*, but not *horizontally*.